# MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: python, mysql

I am not getting the error can anyone help??

This is the query to be executed:

```
sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload2 (ID,hostype,type,group_id,uuid,deviceid) values ({},{},{},{},{},{}) ; '.format(*rowdata)
cursor.execute(sqlquery)
```

The list of data :

```
rowdata = [u'android', u'TSC', u'airtime-ctg', u'guest', u'guest', u'8354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002', u'77c7600c502a3d15']
```

The error:

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002)' at line 1")

Comment: If you use `format` to insert strings into your statement, you end up with unquoted strings, e.g. `" ... values (android, tsc...)"`, which SQL won't understand.

Comment: `type` is a reserved word, enclose it in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use string formatting to insert values. The specific problem is because doing this does not quote those things that need to be strings; but you are also unnecessarily exposing yourself to other problems, such as SQL injection.

Use the built-in parameter support:

```
sqlquery = 'insert into ctg_payload2 (ID,hostype,type,group_id,uuid,deviceid) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ; '
cursor.execute(sqlquery, rowdata)
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it still gives an error   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Well, you also have seven items in rowdata but only six fields to put them in.